# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') _onViewApp ln 17

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I did find this question in a few other places, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue with any of the help given. I got most of the code so far from this article -

https://medium.com/@austinhale/building-a-mobile-app-in-10-days-with-react-native-c2a7a524c6b4

Some of the APIs were outdated, but most of them I was able to replace with the new version - One of the APIs i changed that might be notable in regards to this question is stackNavigator -> createStackNavigator

My code is as follows:

Apps.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    FlatList,
    StatusBar,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import AppItem from './AppItem';

export default class Apps extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            apps: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Good Business',
                    description: 'Make millions investing in mindtree minds',
                    thumbnail: 'https://img12.androidappsapk.co/300/f/5/1/com.nse.bse.sharemarketapp.png'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Troll WhatsApp SOS ONLY',
                    description: 'Have a laugh by reading all the comments in the group chat made by your coworkers',
                    thumbnail: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-l/256/WhatsApp-icon.png'
                }

            ]
        }
    }

    _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <AppItem
            id={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
            thumbnail={item.thumbnail}
        />
    );

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id.toString();

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar
                    barStyle="light-content"
                />
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.apps}
                    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    }
});
```

router.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import Apps from './screens/Apps';
import Gallery from './screens/Gallery';
import Garage from './screens/Garage';
import News from './screens/News';
import Support from './screens/Support';
import ViewApp from './screens/ViewApp';

let screen = Dimensions.get('window');

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    'Apps': {
        screen: Apps,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Apps',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon raised name="ios-apps-outline" type="ionicon" size={28} color={tintColor} />
        },
    },
    'News': {
        screen: News,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'News',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon raised name="newspaper-o" type="font-awesome" size={28} color={tintColor} />
        },
    },
    'Garage': {
        screen: Garage,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Garage',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon raised name="garage" type="material-community" size={28} color={tintColor} />
        },
    },
    'Gallery': {
        screen: Gallery,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Gallery',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon raised name="picture" type="simple-line-icon" size={28} color={tintColor} />
        },
    },
    'Support': {
        screen: Support,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Support',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon raised name="ios-person-outline" type="ionicon" size={28} color={tintColor} />
        },
    },
});

export const AppsStack = createStackNavigator({
    Apps: {
        screen: Apps,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            header: null,
        }),
    },
    ViewApp: {
        screen: ViewApp,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            header: null,
            tabBarVisible: false,
            gesturesEnabled: false
        }),
    },
});

export const createRootNavigator = () => {
    return createStackNavigator(
        {
            AppsStack: {
                screen: AppsStack,
                navigationOptions: {
                    gesturesEnabled: false
                }
            },
            Tabs: {
                screen: Tabs,
                navigationOptions: {
                    gesturesEnabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            headerMode: "none",
            mode: "modal"
        }
    );
};
```

AppItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Text,
    Image,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { ViewApp } from './ViewApp';

export default class AppItem extends Component {

    _onViewApp = () => {
        let id = this.props.id;
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewApp', { id: id })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onViewApp}>
                <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: this.props.thumbnail }}
                        style={styles.thumbnail}
                        resizeMode="contain" />
                    <View style={styles.rowText}>
                        <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>
                            {this.props.title}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>
                            {this.props.description}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    rowContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        height: 100,
        padding: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginTop: 15,
        borderRadius: 4,
        shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1, },
        shadowColor: '#CCC',
        shadowOpacity: 1.0,
        shadowRadius: 1
    },
    title: {
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingTop: 5,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#777'
    },
    description: {
        paddingLeft: 10,
        marginTop: 5,
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#777'
    },
    thumbnail: {
        flex: 1,
        height: undefined,
        width: undefined
    },
    rowText: {
        flex: 4,
        flexDirection: 'column'
    }
});
```

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html), `this.props.navigation` will only be automatically added to *screens*, not all components. So whatever it is that makes a component a *screen* (I don't use react-navigation), you're not doing it for `AppItem`.

Comment: You've tagged [tag:react-router], but you're not using it, are you? You're using [tag:react-navigation], right?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your onPress functionality in AppItem.js like below. Use arrow function inside your onPress **onPress={() => this._onViewApp()}**. Because Arrow function does not create the context "this". It refers to the context of the component that it was wrapped in. For **lexical this** refer this [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { ViewApp } from './ViewApp';

export default class AppItem extends Component {

    _onViewApp(){
        let id = this.props.id;
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewApp', { id: id })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onViewApp()}>
                <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: this.props.thumbnail }}
                        style={styles.thumbnail}
                        resizeMode="contain" />
                    <View style={styles.rowText}>
                        <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>
                            {this.props.title}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>
                            {this.props.description}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same 'undefined is not an object evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate'. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: @jacob, have you used like this onPress={() => this._onViewApp()}

Comment: yes still getting the same error =\. Do you know of a way i can restructure my router.js page?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to follow up for everyone who's having the same issue. I just included `withNavigation from 'react-native-navigation';` and exported at the end of the component like so `export default withNavigation(AppItem);`.